# How to create public S3 bucket in Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless

I have the following Servlerless config that is trying to create a public access S3 bucket that I can use for hosting images for a website. I want to make sure that it has GetObject access to anybody since they will be public images.

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  timeout: 25
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - 's3:GetObject'
            - 's3:PutBucketPolicy'
          Resource:
            - 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*'


resources:
  Resources:

    WebImagesBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: my-bucket-name
        # AccessControl: PublicRead
        # PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        #   BlockPublicAcls: false
        #   BlockPublicPolicy: false
        #   IgnorePublicAcls: false
        #   RestrictPublicBuckets: false

    PublicReadGetObject:
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      Properties: 
        Bucket:
          Ref: "WebImagesBucket"
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Sid: PublicReadGetObject
              Action:
                - 's3:GetObject'
              Resource:
                - 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*'
              Principal: "*"
```

I am creating the S3 bucket resource but creating the `PublicReadGetObject` policy fails with a 403:

```
CREATE_FAILED: PublicReadGetObject (AWS::S3::BucketPolicy)
Resource handler returned message: "Access Denied (Service: S3, Status Code: 403
```

Do I need to update the provider iam to have some other policy actions?

I tried using AccessControl but seems like that has been deprecated in favour of policy.

Any help on getting this working would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to account-level or default bucket-level [Block Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html). See [Configuring Block Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html#configuring-block-public-access). You will need to disable BPA if you want to put a bucket policy that allows public access.

Also, note that `s3:PutBucketPolicy` is a bucket-level action, not object-level, so the ARN `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*` is incorrect. It needs to be `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name`, for example:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  timeout: 25
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - 's3:GetObject'
          Resource:
            - 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*'
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - 's3:PutBucketPolicy'
          Resource:
            - 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name'
```

Comment: Thanks, I will update it to be a bucket level action.

Comment: I am using an admin user which has full permissions so don't think it's account-level access

Comment: All new buckets have Block Public Access enabled by default. You have to disable it explicitly, at or following bucket creation time. So, supply the relevant PublicAccessBlockConfiguration properties on AWS::S3::Bucket and ensure that you don't have account-level BPA enabled.

Comment: You were right. I needed to add `PublicAccessBlockConfiguration` to my bucket properties